# C semaphores: sem_wait throwing inexplicable error

Tags: c, semaphore

I'm working on a problem which we have to use semaphores to solve. I have an array which contains two semaphores, `gsem`, and given certain conditions call `sem_wait(&(gsem[me]))`, which is supposed to waiting until that particular process is woken up. However, for some reason it gives me the error `Bad file descriptor`. I looked up `sem_wait` and the Open Group spec says this is not an error `sem_wait` can cause. This is making my whole program crazy and I have no idea why this is failing.

EDIT: Offending code, as requested.

```
120     sem_wait(&mutex);
121     if (inside[opp] > 0 || waiting[opp] > 0) {
122         sem_wait(&screen);
123         printf("%s %u waiting\n", names[me], t);
124         sem_post(&screen);
125         waiting[me]++;
126         sem_post(&mutex);
127         int hg = sem_wait(&(gsem[me]));
128         if (hg < 0)
129             printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
130     }
```

I should note this is a homework assignment for which we are required to use semaphores. The professor calls it the "unisex bathroom". Either men and women can use it, but not simultaneously. `inside[opp]` is the number of people of the opposite sex in the bathroom. `waiting[opp]` is the number of the opposite sex waiting to use it. `screen` is a semaphore which locks access to `stdout`. The solution is based on a solution to the readers/writers problem given in our textbook which uses passing the baton.

I should also note that we first had to code a solution in Ada and then convert it to C. My Ada solution works, and I translated it verbatim. I'm sure it's some minor syntactical detail. Lastly, I'm working on Snow Leopard, if that helps.

Comment: Show the code :-) Well, the minimal version of the code that still has the problem.

Comment: Please show your code, also list what platforms/OSes you are targeting. Also, why not use mutexes? Semaphores aren't as fast or as robust, depending on the OS/implementation

Comment: Sam, mutex is short for mutual exclusion _semaphore_, a particular class of semaphore where the resource limit is 1. And, even if the OP was using other semaphores, it's probably because, and I quote, "we have to use semaphores". :-)

Comment: Yes, I know what a mutex is thanks... but certain types of mutexes are faster than the posix semaphore. Futexes, kernel mutexes, etc. Hence my question.

Comment: Added offending code for reference. Also details about the problem and my system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep in mind that the Single UNIX Spec may not necessarily be the controlling document in your case. Granted, it probably should be, but since you haven't actually specified the platform, it may be that you're in an environment that decided to follow different rules and/or have other return codes.

A couple of things to check.

1/ Are you *sure* that `sem_wait` is returning -1? I've seen coders simply check `errno` following a call, not realising that most calls don't set it to zero on success, rather they simply leave it alone. It's possible that such a situation would arise if `errno` were set to `EBADF` *before* the `sem_wait` call.

2/ Have you followed all the rules in creating the semaphores, such as initialising them?

3/ Are you referring to a valid semaphore? Primarily, are you certain that the `me` index is not out of range?

Short of seeing some code, that's about all the advice I have to give.

---

One thing I found with a cursory google of `sem_wait ebadf` is [here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/darwin-dev//2008/Oct/msg00029.html). Turns out this was a problem with using `errno` in a threaded environment without including the correct headers.

By doing that, the global `errno` *value* was being used rather than the correct threaded *macro* (which would give the thread-specific `errno`).

Whether that's your problem, I have no idea, but it may be worth looking into.

---

And following that chain of messages a little more closely, there are some other possibilities.

4/ Are you using `sem_init` to initialise the semaphores. If so, check its return value. The messages are from 2008 so it may be dated information, but OSX may still not support `sem_init`, preferring `sem_open` (see [here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/darwin-dev//2008/Oct/msg00044.html)). You really should check the return codes from *all* your `sem_` functions as well, just to be certain (if you're using `sem_init` for them all (and if it's unsupported) and are only checking one, you may find that they're *all* failing).

5/ There is (was?) a [race condition](http://lists.apple.com/archives/darwin-dev//2008/Oct/msg00028.html) in the thread `errno` function chain under OSX where the `__error` function called another library call `pthread_self` before using `errno` (in main thread, or `current_thread->errno` in other threads). Technically this is not allowed and there was a small window where problems could occur.

Comment: I'm including `errno.h` so that shouldn't be a problem according to that site.

Comment: Wow you're right, `sem_init` isn't supported. Not even a man page. Goddammit, Apple. Thanks, paxdiablo.