# Why doesn't my mutex work properly in a multi-process C application?

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, semaphore

I am hacking away at a uni assignment and have come across a problem with my code which is supposed to spawn 2 processes, where the second process waits for the 1st to complete before executing.  This is what I have so far:

```
sem_t mutex;
int producer; int consumer;
sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);
producer = fork();
consumer = fork();

if (producer == 0) {
    if (VERBOSE) printf("Running producer\n");
    /* down semaphore */
    sem_wait(&mutex);
    /* START CRITICAL REGION */
    get_files(N);
    /* END CRITICAL REGION */
    /* up semaphore */
    sem_post(&mutex);
    if (VERBOSE) printf("Ending producer\n");
    exit(0);
}

if (consumer == 0) {
    if (VERBOSE) printf("Running consumer\n");
    /* down semaphore */
    sem_wait(&mutex);
    /* START CRITICAL REGION */
    /* do stuff */
    /* END CRITICAL REGION */
    /* up semaphore */
    sem_post(&mutex);
    if (VERBOSE) printf("Ending consumer\n");
    exit(0);
}
/* parent waits for both to complete */
wait(NULL);
```

*Now, I know that in the "real-world" this is really stupid.  If my 'consumer' does nothing while until my 'producer' is finished, then you might as well not have 2 processes like this, but the assignment is trying to illustrate a race-condition, so that why we've been specifically told to do it this way.*

So, my problem is that the consumer process isn't waiting for the producer.  I assumed that since the semaphore was taken down in the producer (`sem_wait(&mutex);`) then it wouldn't be available to the consumer until `sem_post(&mutex);` is called in the producer.

Additionally, as best as I can tell, the line `wait(NULL);` isn't waiting for both processes to complete.

Have I critically misunderstood something?

Comment: You create processes NOT threads.

Comment: fork shares memory... it should see and be able to use the mutexes just the same no? (i may be well off here, i've not tried it)

Comment: @tobyodavies: I said it because of the phrase "supposed to spawn 2 threads"

Comment: @tur1ng, fair enough i suppose thats why it was a comment, not an answer ;) makes sense...

Comment: @tobyodavies: No, `fork()` created processes do not share memory (unless the memory has specifically been mapped as `MAP_SHARED`).

Comment: My bad, question modified, we're supposed to be forking PROCESSES, not threads as originally indicated, sorry for this mistake.

Comment: @caf, just re-read the man page and you are right! it uses Copy-on-write (which is probably what confused me)...

Comment: @tobyodavies: are you sure **fork** shares memory? I think it DUPLICATES memory from parent to child...

Comment: In a way, forked processes do share memory. But as soon as one of the processes write to it, it will receive its own copy (the whole page will be copied, I believe). This is to speed up the forking process and copy memory only when necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because you `fork` the producer thread first doesn't mean the OS will schedule it to run first - its quite possible that the consumer actually runs and gets the lock first.

Also, you should check the return value of `sem_wait` - it is posible to return from it without holding the semaphore.

It is also quite possible (as several people have noted in comments) that semaphores may simply not work across `fork`ed processes

EDIT - if you pass a non-zero value to argument 2 of `sem_init(sem_t *sem, int pshared, unsigned  value)` when initializing posix semaphores *will* work across processes

EDIT - See [here](http://linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2007/05/24/semaphores-in-linux.html?page=5) for a much better explanation than i could give, complete with source code to do nearly exactly what you want

Comment: Ok, I looked into your suggestion, and it seems as though NEITHER semaphore locks are being granted.  Both `sem_wait(&mutex);` lines return a value of -1 which Google tells me means a failure.  What should I do now? (P.S. I guess thats why my `wait(NULL);` isn't working either then, huh?

Comment: Yes, the point being that you need to actually call sem_init, and check the status of sem_wait.

Comment: you should do `while(sem_wait(mutex)!=0);` as a simplest suggestion (note the ';' - loop w/o doing anything)

Comment: I've modified the question to include the `sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);` line which I have in my program.  Does it look correct?

Comment: no, you need a non-zero second argument to allow semaphore state to be shared between children - i.e. `sem_init(&mutex,TRUE,0)`

Comment: Changed the waits to `while(sem_wait(mutex)!=0);` and the app waited on them forever.  No luck.

Comment: changed the `sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);` to: `sem_init(&mutex, 1, 1);` - and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: is the `sem_init` returning sucessfully?

Comment: Checking errno *apparently* the error coming back from the `sem_wait(&mutex)` line is "Bad file descriptor"  which seems like a weird error for it to throw.

Comment: ah ha! sem_init WAS throwing an error: "Function not implemented" according to errno!  But I'm not entirely sure what to do with this knowledge.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752085/c-semaphores-sem-wait-throwing-inexplicable-error for that error

Comment: Sigh - i am using OSX too!  Will try using `sem_open` and see what happens.

Comment: Does sem_open use the same parameters?  Replaced sem_init with sem_open and its now failing with "No such file or directory"  Or perhaps is the return not 0 as it is with sem_init?

Comment: sem_open behaves _very_ differently to sem_init... see man pages but you should be able to work it out http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/sem_open.html

Comment: yup I got it thanks dude, you've been a bigger help than you probably realise.  Without your help I possible would have failed, but now its working like I want.

Answer (score 11):

You should have error-checking on your semaphore calls.  Use `perror()` to display the error if `sem_wait()`, `sem_init()` or `sem_post()` returns non-zero.

Secondly, you a creating more processes than you think.  Your first `fork()` results in a parent (with `producer` non-zero) and a child (with `producer` zero).  *Both* processes then execute the second `fork()`, so you now have *four* processes.

Thirdly, the `sem_t` variable must be shared between the processes, so it must be stored in a shared memory region.  The easiest way to achieve this is with `mmap()`:

```
sem_t *sem = mmap(NULL, sizeof *sem, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
```

(Execute that prior to the `sem_init()` and the first `fork()`).

Forthly, it's not defined which process will run first, so you can't rely on the producer thread calling `sem_wait()` before the consumer does.  Instead, initialise the semaphore to zero with `sem_init()`, and *only* call `sem_wait()` in the consumer - this will block the consumer.  The producer executes, and calls `sem_post()` when it is done, which allows the consumer to proceed.

The `sem_init()` call should specify `pshared` as non-zero and `value` as 0, so it should look like:

```
if (sem_init(sem, 1, 0) != 0) {
    perror("sem_init");
    exit(1);
}
```

Fifth, `wait(NULL)` only waits for a single child process to exit.  Call it twice to wait for two child processes.

Comment: You've actually spotted bug #2, so thanks for that.  The question as been modified though to update you on the other elements of your answer.  The short of it though, while your correct - in this situation, i dont think thats the problem.

Comment: according to O'Reily (http://linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2007/05/24/semaphores-in-linux.html?page=5) you only need shared mem if the processes are not parent/child

Comment: `sem_wait` will just block and never succeed on a semaphore with an initial value of 0 no? I may have misread the man page, but my understanding was that a semaphore's value represents the number of additional 'users' it can handle so that a semaphore w/ value=1 is equivalent to a mutex...

Comment: @tobyodavies: `sem_wait()` will block on a semaphore with a value of 0, until the semaphore is posted.  This is exactly the behaviour that is desired here - an initial value of `0`, a `sem_wait()` at the beginning of the consumer and a `sem_post()` at the end of the producer.  In this case the value of the semaphore is "number of things that have been produced and not yet consumed".

Comment: true, i was still trying to fix the first bug, you're way ahead of me

Comment: Ok, awesome.  Your right, except that the semaphore DOESN'T need to be in the shared memory segment.  It's working just fine without it.  Thanks so much for your help though, it was great, and you actually saw and solved another bug I was having (producer running twice) so thanks a tonne.  The problem was OSX, which apparently doesn't implement `sem_init`.  I am using `mutex = sem_open("mutex", O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 1);` and it is working just as expected (but i had to change the waits/posts `sem_wait(mutex);` but im going to give the answer to @tobyodavies (he needs it more than you) :P

Comment: @Ash: The semaphore doesn't need to be in shared memory if you're using a named semaphore obtained with `sem_open()` - only unnamed "memory-based" sempahores obtained with `sem_init()` do.

Answer (score 1):

Have you provided complete code in the question?

If so, you are missing semaphore initialization. You have to call either `sem_init` or `sem_open` prior to using the semaphore.

Read [here](http://linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2007/05/24/semaphores-in-linux.html?page=4).

**EDIT** You are specifying `pshared` = 0 in the `sem_init` call. This makes the semaphore process-local (i.e. it can be used only to synchronize threads of one process). `fork` creates a child process, so the semaphore does not do anything useful.

> If pshared has value 0, then the
>   semaphore is shared between the
>   threads of a process. If pshared is
>   non-zero, then the semaphore is shared
>   between processes.

(the quote is from the link above)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't think mutexes will work with processes. The reason being that forked processes don't actually share memory. They will be able to read the same memory as it was before the fork, but whenever one of them writes to memory the new process will receive its own copy.

Second, you might have to initialize your mutexes, or else usage of them might be undefined.