# C++ Macs OS X semaphore.h: trouble with `sem_open()` and `sem_wait()`

Tags: c++, macos, semaphore

```
#include <semaphore.h>

sem_t* x;

int main () 
{
    x = sem_open("x", O_CREAT, 0, 0);;
    sem_wait(x); sem_wait(x); sem_wait(x);
    std::cout << "\ndone\n";
}
```

This code shouldn't even pass the first `sem_wait()` but on my system it reaches the end of `main()`. Everything I have read, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413785/sem-init-on-os-x/1452182#1452182) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752085/c-semaphores-sem-wait-throwing-inexplicable-error/2752182#2752182), say that, although Mac OS X does not support `sem_init()`, it does support `sem_open()`. However, using `sem_open()` as above hasn't fixed the problem. I'm running OS X 10.5.7.

Comment: You need to check for the return value of `sem_open`. If it's `SEM_FAILED` you need to look at `errno`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try putting `sem_unlink("x");` before `sem_open()`, I'm sure it's not your first attempt on it. And mode of 0 won't let you do much with it, unless you remove it. Also, do check your calls for errors, it will if not resolve, but, at least, amend your questions.

Comment: `sem_unlink("x");` did the trick. Does this mean that a named semaphore persists after the calling process ends, unless it is explicitly unlinked, thus causing `O_CREAT` to fail due to the semaphore already being present? But actually I still don't quite see how that would account for the behavior.

Comment: Yes, it does persist. The problem is not the `O_CREAT` flag, it's supposed to create semaphore if it doesn't exist (unlike `O_EXCL` which supposed to make it fail if it exists). The problem is that semaphore exists and restricts all kind of access (mode of 0). That's why you need to unlink it first.

Comment: Kewl, that's it! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Permissions of 0 to `sem_open` mean that nobody can access the semaphore. You really should add proper error checking -- it will tell you which function is failing and way.

Comment: What mode should I set it to if I want to give the calling process unrestricted access?

Comment: So do I :) Not sure, though, it's about the calling *process*, but as close as you can get.